# Typescript: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I tried to integrate a library named -> `YAML` in my codebase.
But I am getting this error when I try to use the library:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/yaml/browser/dist/nodes/YAMLSeq.js 93:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (93:14)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     value: function toJSON(_, ctx) {
|       var seq = [];
>       if (ctx?.onCreate) ctx.onCreate(seq);
|       var i = 0;
|       var _iterator = _createForOfIteratorHelper(this.items),
```

This is my `tsconfig.js` file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/",
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "paths": {
    "common/*": ["common/*"],
    "modules/*": ["modules/*"],
    "store/*": ["store/*"],
    "fac/*": ["fac/*"],
    "i18n/*": ["i18n/*"],
    "utils/*": ["utils/*"],
    "data/*": ["data/*"]
  },
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "typings"],
  "sourceMap": true,
  "module": "es6",
  "target": "es5",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "jsx": "react",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
  "lib": ["es5", "es2015", "dom", "scripthost"],
  "keyofStringsOnly": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noUnusedParameters": true
},
"include": [
  "./src/**/*.ts",
  "./src/**/*.tsx", "src/utils/Link/index.tsx"
]
}
```

I feel there is some error with my `compilerOptions` -> `lib`

I am not able to understand what I need to do here ?
Any hint would be helpful.